# Catching scope assignment errors in directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a directive that is doing something like:

```
scope: {
    foo: '=',
    other_var: '=',
    yet_another_var: '='
}
```

Now, suppose I'm creating a DOM object using

```
<div my-directive
    foo="model_data"
></div>
```

Being `model_data` a variable visible in the scope of my application.

Now, suppose I do

```
<div my-directive
    foo="/(6nN9s@#@#½476ae@€đŋđ¶"
></div>
```

(random string assigned to `foo`)

Now, because angular can't parse `/(6nN9s@#@#½476ae@€đŋđ¶` as valid variable name, the entire directive will crash.

Is there a way I can tell angular to `try/catch` or just "skip" this `foo` assignment and resume with the rest of the scope (`other_var`, `yet_another_var`)?

EDIT: Example/demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/9bzpWl?p=preview

Comment: validate or normalize your value before assigning it to that scope object and use a fallback default

Comment: @charlietfl The directive is used by third parties, thus I can't validate the value passed to `foo`.

Comment: no there isn't a way to do that in angular, sorry. but how would that even happen or why would you even want that to "work" ? it is a kind of validation from angularjs to prevent missuses at "compile" time (yeah javascript doesnt compile etc...) - there is no reason to not throw an error when someone is miss-using your directive that hard

Comment: Why can't the random string be assigned to $scope.model_data?

Comment: @PatrickKelleter Let's say that `foo` can be a variable that lives in the app's scope or a string of some sort (for example, a JSON string or a URL).

Comment: Then you probably need to pass as attribute string and do your own binding after you evaluate it inside directive

Comment: @camden_kid You're getting it wrong. The random string is assigned to `foo`, not to the `model_data` variable.

Comment: @charlietfl How can I reach the caller's scope?

Comment: try using `$parent` or `element.scope()` . Not sure if this would be nested inside another isolated scope or not

Comment: @charlietfl That won't get me what I want if the directive is used inside (multiple) `ng-if` as those create their own scopes.

Comment: What about passing in a config object?

Comment: @charlietfl Same error will happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829979/catching-scope-assignment-errors-in-directive-scope#comment59327182_35829979

Comment: Create a demo that simulates issue. I understand the error but not sure why you can't evaluate a config object passed in

Comment: @charlietfl http://plnkr.co/edit/9bzpWl?p=preview

Comment: Might help: `It's also possible to watch the evaluated value shallowly with $watchCollection: use =* or =*attr (=*? or =*?attr if the attribute is optional).`

Comment: Demo is far too trivial to know what needs to be done

Comment: @charlietfl The expected behavior in my demo is the directive not to crash, no matter what is passed to `foo`. Also, if the value of `foo` is a variable that exists in the caller's scope, bind to it.

Comment: What if foo doesn't exist? Or is added later in a `$http`? Not enough criteria to know what your app needs

Comment: @charlietfl Then just make `foo`'s value whatever it was passed, as string.

Comment: Happy to help but with more real world test cases in demo

Comment: @charlietfl What is wrong with that demo? I want `foo` to be binded to a variable in the parent's scope (if that variable exists), else I want `foo`'s value to just be the string it was passed when the directive was created.

Comment: did you try suggestion from comment above using `$watchcollection` syntax? Was taken from `$compile` docs

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, same error: http://plnkr.co/edit/HOsaOUOF3W3XTDJ0YnkJ?p=preview

Comment: But why would anyone put that url string in? Assuming it was in a repeat a variable would be passed in

Comment: @charlietfl Because `foo` can (should) accept a variable name from the caller's scope that holds an array of objects, a JSON string that can be parsed to an array of objects or a URL pointing to a JSON array of objects.

Comment: but the url string wouldn't be in that attribute value

Comment: @charlietfl To avoid cluttering the directive with different attributes, I want to make a single attribute be able to accept different types of data.

Comment: Well if you think something like that will happen then you need to dig deep into how to use `$eval` and `$parse`

Comment: @charlietfl Any specific tips/links/docs about $eval and $parse?

Comment: angular docs and google

Comment: @charlietfl Believe me, I already tried that before posting this question. Do you have anything that could be actually useful to my question? Saying "you should dig deep in XYZ" doesn't really help me.

Comment: or build all the scope yourself from the string attributes with lots of `if(attrs.foo)`